Webscraping program is hanging when site is not responding
I have developed a program for scraping data from a climate website.
The website has an option for choosing the date. Based on that, it will show the climatic parameters for some 500 stations.
My program opens the website, inputs a series of dates through a for-loop, and scrapes the site for data. This works fine.
But there is a inherent problem with this website. For some older dates, this website hangs sometimes. During such time I want my webscraper program to load default data. But the program simply hangs.
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanicalsoup
import time
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.session.timeout = (10,10)

url = "https://myclimate.com"
browser.open(url)

dateList = pd.date_range(start = '2023-01-01', end = '2023-02-02').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame()

print("----")

for dte in dateList:

    browser.select_form('form[action="https://myclimate.com]')
    browser['date_on'] = dte
    try:
        response =browser.submit_selected()
        print(response)
        # my webscrap code and it will populate df
    except requests.Timeout:
        #df will be populated with default value
df.to_csv('data_year_J2023.csv')

When myclimate.com hangs for some date, the program also hangs.

Would be great if you could provide some more specific details and your expectation as well - In addition, it is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap is something completely different.

The program needs to get data from the website for a series of dates. The data is mainly rainfall received by different places on that date. I wnat to gather the data and further make computations. My problem is that sometimes the website hangs. In that case I just need to skip the loop and go for next date

@user3462318 What is the URL?

https://beta-tnsmart.rimes.int/index.php/MIS/Rainfall/raingauge_stations

In my opinion, a simple post request with a timeout parameter is sufficient. If the timeout takes effect or another error occurs, simply insert a default dataframe.
Another observation is that the results are generated much more reliably on HTTP instead of HTTPS, maybe the server has an issue there.
Example
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://beta-tnsmart.rimes.int/index.php/MIS/Rainfall/raingauge_stations'

data = []

for d in ['2021-05-01','2023-05-01','2024-05-01']:
    try:
        post_data = {
            'date_on': d,
            'search_submit': 'View Data'
        }
        response = requests.post(url, data=post_data, timeout=10)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            df = pd.read_html(response.content)[0].droplevel(0,axis=1)
            df['Date'] = d
            data.append(df)
        else:
            print(f'Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}')
            data.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date':[d]}))
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print('The request timed out')
        data.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date':[d]}))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
        data.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date':[d]}))

pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)

